# How to send LARGE data from c++ to python in a fast way on Linux?

Tags: python, c++, linux, ipc

What is the fast enough way (about 40~50Hz) to send large data (RGB image data: 320*240*3) from c++ process to python process (and small size of float data from python to c++) on Linux? Note: the two processes are running at the same PC.

I have tried:

1. UDP
2. shared memory

**For UDP:**
The message to be sent is larger than the UDP message constrain (65535), so directly using `sendto()` will get error: *Message too long*. And I also doubt whether it is a fast way (about 40~50Hz is ok).

**For shared memory:**
Shared memory seems to be a fast way to send image from c++ to c++. But since there is no pointer in python, I do not find a way to read and write data in shared memory.

So is there a fast way to do IPC things above? Or maybe a good way to read and write *unsigned char* and **float** type values to shared memory in python?

Comment: You don't send all the data at once. You send it in chunks. Let's say you have 5 GB of data to send. You don't send the 5 GB of data all at once, much pointless anyway. Also if your data is important and you cannot lose any of it then go with TCP instead of UDP.

Comment: Hertz is not a unit of throughput. Do you mean you want to send 320*240*3 octets of data, 50 times per second, (10.98 MiBps or so) over IPC?

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis Yes, I want to send unsigned char type 320*240*3 data about 40~50 times per second.

Comment: That makes around 10 MBytes/s. You could make a RAMdisk and write the frames to it from the C++ program as files and then open the files in Python and read them. The size of the RAMdisk will allow the C++ program to get a bit ahead, or the Python to get a bit behind - i.e. buffer speed variations. https://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/943-create-a-ram-disk-in-linux  Even a smallish 512MB RAMdisk would allow you 50 seconds of buffering.

Comment: Don't even need a RAMdisk. Any disk will do, the disk cache will handle it. But just write to `/tmp/`. It can be a physical disk with cache, `tmpfs` or something else that's appropriate on the specific target system.

Comment: @MSalters Could you maybe explain your comment - why would you want to make the disk unnecessarily busy? Surely a RAMdisk is faster and it saves making the disk busy with writes that are not needed as the point is just to make a temporary data transfer.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Because the disk isn't actually used. The file is overwritten before it's flushed. Typically Linux flushes after 30 seconds No data gets old enough to hit the disk, or even close. The expected lifetime here is 20-25 **milli**seconds

Comment: @MSalters I see, many thanks for taking the time to explain.

Answer (score 2):

[mmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap) the same file in both applications, and then use a [domain socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) to coordinate use of the mmapped space.

Comment: Does this means I must first save the frames on the disk and then use mmap like mmap(fileno, len) in python? I haven't used mmap before, so the comment may be strange :-)

Comment: No, just create an empty file of the appropriate size and mmap it in both C++ and Python. You can then treat it as a bytewise memory space in each.

Comment: But these two processes will probably interact for days, so I cannot save the frames to a file as it would ever-growing.

Comment: Do you really need to retain the old frames after processing?

Comment: Yes, about millions of frames... Trying to train a neural network.

Comment: You use that `mmap` memory as shared memory (the writes to the "file" on specific address is visible from the other process too), you don't `msync` it to write the content also to the file physically. If you want also to store the frame on disk, save it separately, I believe you may want to save in PNG or LZMA or some other lossless compression scheme to save disk space. Especially if you plan to store only some of the frames. If you want to store ALL frames, stop doing IPC, just save frames from C++ to disk (you would anyway), and keep reading them from python, OS will cache the recent files.

Answer (score -1):

On Linux, you could try pipes. One program will "write" to the pipe file while the other program will "read" it.  In this case, the C program will write the array of image bytes to the pipe and the python program will read the byte stream.
You'll have to find a clever way to have a delimiter between frames unless the frame size is known in advance.

http://www.python-course.eu/pipes.php

Otherwise, a TCP socket would suffice.  But be careful - there's a lot that can go wrong here if don't pay attention to the return values from all the functions or make assumptions about message lengths.

Answer (score -1):

you can combine both applications memory with tools like swig.

also you can use namedpipe